ruby multi-stage docker build rails was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on actioncable
I am writing a multi-stage docker build but I am getting this error
In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
            activesupport was resolved to 7.1.3.3, which depends on
              bigdecimal

Muti-stage Dockerfile
FROM ruby:slim-bullseye as base

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN gem install bundler

COPY Gemfile* ./

RUN bundle install
    
# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Stage 2: Final stage
FROM ruby:slim-bullseye as base

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app .

# Expose port 3000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Rails server
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

But this single stage Dockerfile works
FROM ruby:slim-bullseye as base

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN gem install bundler

COPY Gemfile* ./

RUN bundle install
    
# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Stage 2: Final stage
FROM ruby:slim-bullseye as base

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app .

# Expose port 3000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the Rails server
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]

How do I resolve this?

Looks like the same docker file

Please share the full error message. The part you shared only describes the dependencies of those gems. The interesting part is missing, in which bundler tells what problem it had with solving those dependencies.
